# Help with .net .ashx files

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

We have an application that has a coulple of .ashx files used to upload files to the server.  The problem we are having is what we we make changes to these files and republish the app, it does not update the .assh files.  Really it does nto make the changes in the code behind.  Everything else is updated.  We are using Visual Studio 2008 and have out prulish settings set to:

Replace Matching files with local copies
Copy all project files

I believe it will work if we delete everythign in the directory first but we do not want to have to do that.  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have run into this and similar problems a number of times and its almost always a mismatch between the live and cached copies of your site.  Generally the answer is to delete your local cache or if developing remotely, delete the website from \server\C$\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files and recompile.

This is also the fix to a number of IDE related glitches.  It's a pain because you have to do a full recompile, but it fixes a ton of issues.